# Setting font-size as percentage on html element: the percentage is relative to...?

Tags: css

Using a percentage value as font-size, we set the font-size to a percent of  the parent element's font size. 
I'm wondering: if I set a percentage value as font-size to the `<html>` tag, what is the parent' element's font size (the html tag has not parent)?

Comment: web browsers base font size (100%) is usually 16px but I guess it would be relative to what the user sets their browser font size to

Comment: I would like to understand if there is a way to retrieve the base font-size in px

Comment: You would have to use js why but do you need it? Just base everything off the fact that everything should start at 16px.  If the user manually changes the settings, then it may be because they are visually impaired so as long as you have used relative units, you should be okay - you cannot program for every eventuality

Answer (score 5):

Base `font-size` depends on browser. Usually it's `16px`. Percentage is calculate based on base `font-size`

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the browser's base font-size

Comment: Do not set `<html>` style, than `$('html').css('font-size')`